# How to validate if a comment was entered in a transition screen using JIRA and Groovy Runner Plugin

Tags: jira-plugin

we'd like to use the Groovy Runner plugin for Jira to validate if a user has entered a comment in a workflow transition screen.

Since this is part of a larger script, we have to stick to Groovy Runner and cannot use another plugin.

Any help how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (transientVars.get("comment")) { ... }
```

Question was answered here by Jamie Echlin:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/279738/how-to-validate-if-a-comment-was-entered-in-a-transition-screen-using-jira-and-groovy-runner-plugin?page=1#279865